# android stop default video recording to get audio focus

Tags: android, android-camera, android-video-player

i am doing a sample Voip Application.When user is recording video using default camera appplication,and incomming voip call comes, i want to stop video recording to get audio focus to my application.

```
mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mAudioFocusListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

private OnAudioFocusChangeListener mAudioFocusListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

        Logger.d(TAG, "--------Audio Focus change: " + focusChange);

        switch(focusChange){
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                Logger.d(TAG, "--------Focus change: AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN" );
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT:
                Logger.d(TAG, "--------Focus change: AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT" );
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK:
                Logger.d(TAG, "--------Focus change: AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK" );
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                Logger.d(TAG, "--------Focus change: AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS" );
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                Logger.d(TAG, "--------Focus change: AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT" );
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                Logger.d(TAG, "--------Focus change: AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK" );                 
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED:
                Logger.d(TAG, "--------Focus change: AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED" );
                break;


        }
    }
};
```

How can i get audio focus when phones native camera is recording a video.?